# PHP First occurance of string before and after index

Tags: php, string

I have a string ex. `abcd.something.dcba` And I have an index ex. 9 (in this case that is `e`) and I would have to get the string between the two `.`s. I do not know how far back the first dot is from the index nor do I know how far the second dot is. So is there any easy way of doing this in php? Also there are a lot more `.`s in the string ex. `a.b.c.d.something.d.c.b.a`

a couple of other examples:

`bef.ore.something.af.t.er` index: 12 = `something`

`bef.ore.something.af.t.er` index: 5 = `ore`

`bef.ore.something.af.t.er` index: 19 = `af`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a starting point, you can try:

```
$input = 'a.b.something.c.def';
$index = 9;
$delimiter = '.';

/*
 * get length of input string
 */
$len = strlen($input);

/*
 * find the index of the first delimiter *after* the index
 */
$afterIdx = strpos($input, $delimiter, $index);

/*
 * find the index of the last delimiter *before* the index 
 * figure out how many characters are left after the index and negate that - 
 * this makes the function ignore that many characters from the end of the string,
 * effectively inspecting only the part of the string up to the index
 * and add +1 to that because we are interested in the location of the first symbol after that
 */
$beforeIdx = strrpos($input, $delimiter, -($len - $index)) + 1; 

/*
 * grab the part of the string beginning at the last delimiter 
 * and spanning up to the next delimiter
 */
$sub = substr($input, $beforeIdx, $afterIdx - $beforeIdx);
echo $sub;
```

Note, at the very minimum you'll need to add some sanity checking for cases where there's no symbol before/after the index.

- [strlen](http://us.php.net/strlen)
- [strpos](http://us.php.net/strpos)
- [strrpos](http://us.php.net/strrpos)
- [substr](http://us.php.net/substr)

Comment: I think this actually works! Could you explain a bit more on what each line does? Thank you!

Comment: @19greg96: added some comments and links to related documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions would be your friend in this case:

```
$regex = '/\.?([\w]+)/';
$string = 'a.b.c.d.something.d.c.b.a';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $result);
print_r($result[1]);
```

Note: If your looking for a specific word, just replace [\w]+ with the word your looking for.

@19greg96 I see what you wanted now, an alternate but similiar approach to 'DCoder's example would be:

```
$string = 'a.b.something.d.c.b.a';
$index = 9;
$delimiter = '.';

$last_index = strpos($string, $delimiter, $index);
$substr = substr($string, 0, $last_index);
$substr = substr($substr, strrpos($substr, $delimiter) + 1);
echo $substr;
```

Comment: A very basic example, accomodating alpha characters in between the periods.

Answer (score 0):

Explode the string into an array and pass it through a foreach():

```
$str='a.b.c.d.something.d.c.b.a';
$parts=explode('.',$str);
foreach($parts as $part) {
    if($part=='something') {
        echo('Found it!');
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If he already knows what the string is equal to for the if statement, there would be no point to trying to find it in the original string. :P

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear enough, but the string is not always the same. So to put it simpler: I have an index in a string, and before and after that index there is some special character / string (the dot in this example) but there are many occurrences of this special char before and after but I need the string between the closest chars: `bef.ore.str[index is somewhere here]ing.aft.er` would be `str[index is somewhere here]ing` but if the index was in the `aft` area than `aft` would be the return.